# Remember Button when another is clicked in java/android

Tags: android, button, onclick, click

I have some Buttons in a ButtonList, and when I click one I set setEnabled(false) in the onClick method, and after clicking another Button I want that he gets enabled again.
So: How can I know which Button of a ButtonList is clicked before, after I click another?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the buttons list that you have is List.

If this is the case then here is how I would do it:

```
Button lastClicked = null;
List<Button> buttons;

public void onClick(View v){
  Button temp = (Button)v;
  temp.setEnabled(false);
  if(lastClicked != null){
    for(Button b : buttons){
      if(b.equals(lastClicked){
        lastClicked = v;
        b.setEnabled(true);
        break;
      }
    }
  }else{
    lastClicked = v;
  }
}
```

This will save the lastClicked, or touched, button and disable it. It will set the button the user has pressed just before and will enable that last clicked button.

Hope this helps.